# Add and remove map layers using radio buttons

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery, combo-box

I've struggled to use radio buttons to toggle multiple map service layers. So far it's fine to add but I can't then add another map service and remove the previous at the same time - I just can't figure out the problem:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {

    var radioValue = $("input[name='exampleSwitch']:checked").val();
    if (radioValue == 'on') {

        map.addLayer(mapidurl);

    } else if (radioValue == 'off') {
        debugger
        map.removeLayer(mapidurl);
    };
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="switch tiny" style="float:right;padding-top:0px;">
      <input class="switch-input" id="switch3" type="radio" name="exampleSwitch">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="switch3">
          <span class="switch-active" value="on" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="switch-inactive" value="off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </label>
</div>
```

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: please explain more ! 
waht do you mean by "can't then add another map service and remove the previous at the same time" ?

Comment: Well when I click on the radio button a map layer is added ie. map.addLayer. When an alternative radio button on the same toc is checked then the previous map service layer is replaced removeLayer (switched off) and a new map layer is added in its place.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using checkboxes instead of radio buttons. The way that your if/then statement is set up seems to indicate there is no default "off" position to begin with (i.e., by having `radioValue == 'off'` trigger `removeLayer`). I successfully used checkboxes with the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="toggleLayers(1);"/><label for="check1">Map Layer Title</label>

var layers = [];
layers[1] = link to layer

// Create function to toggle layers in array on and off
function toggleLayers(i){
    if(layers[i].getMap()==null) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

The code above was modified from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409598/toggle-multiple-kml-kml-layers-in-google-maps-api-v3. And though for Google Maps API rather than ArcGIS, could be helpful in refining your toggle code.